# Synching files between home & work without leaving local copy at work

Tags: windows-xp, sync

The total size of files is about 20Mb (notes, some Word documents and several other types of "office" files including one Chrome profile folder) although not all of them would be changed every day.

I would like to have some kind of online folder to which I have access, from let's say Windows Explorer when I am connected, but not when I am disconnected from that service. A kind of synching service but which, after disconnecting, deletes the local copy of the files without deleting the online copy.

I have no experience with those services, so was wondering, if anyone could recommend one that would satisfy the above, and perhaps shortly describe his experience with it.

Comment: I guess I don't know your full requirements/goals; have you tried or considered just using Google Docs?

Comment: @user142485 - I've tried using Google Docs and Google Drive so far. Google Docs it seems do something to files sometimes (I've had problems opening some word Files afterwards) and Google Drive, I've been unable to configure so that after I delete the local copy, it keeps the online one.

Comment: @user142485 - "my full requirements/goals"? Well, just as they're described above. Is there anything that interests you that I should further describe?

Comment: It would probably just be easier to use a flash drive but I assume you don't want to carry it around.

Comment: @user142485 - Actually, I could use a flash drive and did until last week when I lost mine. I am currently situated in a place where I can't buy a new one, and if ordered online, it would probably take a month or so to arrive :/ (but yes, a flash drive would otherwise solve my problem).

Comment: If it deletes the local copy, then it wouldn't be "synching".  It sounds like you can essentially accomplish what you need by just using the browser-based version of whichever service, be it Google Drive, Dropbox, or SkyDrive (my personal recommendation), or Box.com.  We might be able to help more if you can tell us why you need the files to be unavailable certain times.  Maybe you could create a Windows user account just for accessing these files, and switch users when you're done?

Comment: @trpt4him - Because it is a computer a lot of people use, and I would like not to leave my personal files there. I don't have admin privileges for account creation.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the requirements you listed, I think [Sky Drive](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/skydrive/skydrive-help#skydrive-help=tab1) is what you're looking for. As far as disconnecting goes, you will have to delete the local contents manually. I have never heard of a service that deletes local folders automatically. This makes sense when you think about it, as these services are for backing up files.

Comment: I don't think Dropbox deletes files on disconnect.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com), 2++GB free, and you can just drag to / from the web interface at work, and have the files sync back to your own PC.

Along similar lines [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com) offers a similar Web and thin client combination.

Both also offer mobile App's to make the Dc's / Notes available on you Phone or Tablet.